# For loops and lists

Tags: python

I recently encountered this problem: I need to write a function that does reverse lookups of a value in a dictionary and return a list of keys that are paired to that value.

I wrote two versions, the first one works but the other doesn't. However, I can't see why.

```
def reverse_lookup(d, v):
  l = []
  for k in d:
      if d[k] == v:
          l.append(k)
  return l

def reverse_lookup(d, v):
  l = []
  for k in d:
      if d[k] == v:
          l = l.append(k)
  return l
```

The second version returns `None` regardless. What's wrong with that? In my understanding, I'm updating the list by writing `l = l.append(k)`, so I should be able to receive a list of keys that are desired.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`append` function returns `None`. So, when you say

```
l = l.append(k)
```

you are reassigning `None` to `l`. In the next iteration, you ll be trying to invoke `append` function on `None`, which will not be there. So, you would have got an error. But if there was only one iteration, then `l` now has `None` and that will be returned.

BTW, you could have done this using comprehension, like this

```
return [key for key, value in d.items() if value == v]
```